# I need to test SAML connection using OneLogin SAML w/encrypt/signed assertions connector. How do I generate a private key to sign OneLogin certificate

Tags: onelogin

I am new to OneLogin setup. I need to test a SAML connection with encrypted/signed assertions from one login to our development server
What are the steps involved with generation of public/private keys and setting this connection?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the private key for encrypting the SAML response. The SP provides you with a public key of their private key pair in the form of a cert. You then configure the Onelogin application to use the public key they give you.

Just to be clear, encrypted and signed are different things. You need to sign the SAML response, but you don't need to encrypt it. You can have both. If you just need the SAML response signed, then that's all handled for you in the OL UI.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks a lot for responding. This is what I am trying to accomplish. Currently we use SAML and I have created OneLogin connection to test it. Now we have a client which wants to use encrypted SAML assertions and I am looking for a way testing this scenario from OneLogin. The problem I have - in order to decrypt encrypted assertions - I need a private key which I can't get, I also can't install my own certificate with public key in it to OneLogin. So what are my options? Please advise

Comment: You shouldn't really need to test it. That's OOB functionality in Onelogin, so I can assure you it works. If they client provides you with their *public* key in the form of a .pem file ( not private as you stated ) and the SP is configured correctly, it will just work. I've used it hundreds of times, and where there is an issue it is usually the wrong cert has been provided, or the SP is not configured correctly. To test it fully, you'd need to build your own SP that is configured to support encrypted SAML Responses, and then generate your own keypair using OpenSSL or similar.

Comment: You can test out of band using these tools as well: https://www.samltool.com/encrypt.php

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am still unsure about one thing here. I do have an application which is used as SAML provider and I use URL from oneLogin to get to this application endpoint. I can test it fine w/out SAML assertions. The payload sent from oneLogin is Encrypted using OneLOgin Certificate. In order do decrypt SAML assertions I need to have a public key from OneLogin. If I try to generate the key pair using OpenSSL - it doesn't do me any good, I can't merge this key into OneLogin Certificate, nor can I decrypt a payload coming from OneLogin using this generated key.

Comment: It sounds like you need to take a step back. The SAML assertion should not be encrypted with a "certificate from Onelogin". If you are encrypting the SAML response or assertion it should be done with a certificate provided by the SP ( application ). The application generates a key pair, and retains ( and protects ) it's private key. It provides it's public key contained in a .pem file to you ( Onelogin ) and you add this to the encryption configuration in the app config in Onelogin. Onelogin encrypts with the SP's public key, and the SP decrypts with it's own private key.

Comment: I'd argue that unless you have a known MiTM such as a CASB, or TLS is stripped at the enterprise border, then encrypting the SAML response doesn't provide you with any additional security anyway.

Comment: So encrypt of the SAML response is the the SP's public key. Provided by the SP to the IdP. Signing of the SAML response is with the IdPs private key, and validated at the SP with the public certificate provided by the IdP to the SP. Two different key pairs in use if you are encrypting AND signing.

Comment: @niall_atlasidentity how to get IdPs private key in OL UI?